# How can one await a result of a boxed future?

Tags: rust, async-await, future

```
use futures::{future, Future};

fn test() -> Box<dyn Future<Output = bool>> {
    Box::new(future::ok::<bool>(true))
}

async fn async_fn() -> bool {
    let result: bool = test().await;
    return result;
}

fn main(){
    async_fn();
    println!("Hello!");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=74c9c1b77cfba385e1dce37edcf29075)

Error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `dyn core::future::future::Future<Output = bool>: std::marker::Unpin` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:8:24
   |
8  |     let result: bool = test().await;
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Unpin` is not implemented for `dyn core::future::future::Future<Output = bool>`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `core::future::future::Future` for `std::boxed::Box<dyn core::future::future::Future<Output = bool>>`
```

Comment: just listen the compiler https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=992be881058088a5c05b02dbee802090

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [the implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/trait.Future.html#implementors):

```rust
impl<F> Future for Box<F>
where
    F: Unpin + Future + ?Sized,
```

Boxed futures only implement the `Future` trait when the future inside the `Box` implements `Unpin`.

Since your function doesn't guarantee that the returned future implements `Unpin`, your return value will be considered to not implement `Future`. You'll not able to `await` it because your type is basically not a `Future`.

The solution from @Stargateur, adding an explicit type boundary to the signature, works ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=992be881058088a5c05b02dbee802090)):

```rust
fn test() -> Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<bool, ()>> + Unpin>
```

If you are using futures-rs, there is a helper type [`BoxFuture`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/future/type.BoxFuture.html). You can use `BoxedFuture` without explicitly stating `Unpin`:

```rust
use futures::future::BoxFuture;

fn test() -> BoxFuture<'static, Result<bool, ()>> {
    Box::pin(async { Ok(true) })
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0f84611fe24a3a2e79f2fc94ecb3c241)

Comment: Thanks a lot as well! Helped me a lot get a better understanding and I like the hint with the futures crate helper.

Answer (score 19):

When it comes to `Box` and `future`, it almost always make sense to use [`Box::pin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.pin) instead of [`Box::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.new):

```
use std::pin::Pin;
use futures::{future, Future};

fn test() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<bool, ()>>>> {
    Box::pin(future::ok(true))
}

async fn async_fn() -> bool {
    test().await.unwrap()
}
```

The reason is quite interesting. `Pin` has a [blanket implementation for `Unpin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#impl-Unpin):

```
impl<P> Unpin for Pin<P> where
    P: Unpin,
```

And the `Box<T>` inside it is [unconditionally `Unpin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-Unpin):

```
impl<T> Unpin for Box<T> where
    T: ?Sized,
```

So a `Pin<Box<dyn Future>>` is a unpinned `Future`. Everything works out, but why `Box` itself doesn't? This is one place where `Deref` gets in the way:

```
impl<T: ?Sized> Deref for Box<T> {
    type Target = T;
}
```

`await` expects an unpinned `Future`, and the `Box<dyn Future>` you created with `Box::new` does contain a `Future`. So it is auto-dereferenced and the `Unpin` is lost unless you explicitly state it that way with `Box<dyn Future + Unpin>`.

---

Edit: @ÖmerErden is right about why `Box<dyn Future>` wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation regarding the Unpin + Box. That helped a lot!

Comment: Side Note: You can await on Box<dyn Future>, By creating Pin wrapper, Example: `Pin::from(Box::new(async {})).await`