# How can I poll a Pin<Option<Box<dyn Future>>?

Tags: asynchronous, rust

When implement a stream within an `Option<Box<dyn Future>` which generated by async function recursively. How to poll a `Pin<Option<Box<dyn Future>>`? thanks.

```rust
use std::{
    future::Future,
    pin::Pin,
    task::{Context, Poll},
};

use futures_util::Stream;

#[pin_project::pin_project]
struct BoxedStream<T, F> {
    #[pin]
    next: Option<String>,
    #[pin]
    inner: Option<Box<dyn Future<Output = T>>>,
    //             ^--- Future generated by async function, it is an opaque type.
    generate: F,
}

impl<T, F> Stream for BoxedStream<T, F>
where
    F: Fn(String) -> (Option<String>, Box<dyn Future<Output = T>>),
{
    type Item = T;

    fn poll_next(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        let mut p = self.as_mut().project();
        if let Some(s) = p.inner.as_mut().as_pin_mut() {
            return match todo!("how to do it here? s.poll(cx)?") {
                result @ Poll::Ready(_) => {
                    p.inner.take();
                    result
                }
                _ => Poll::Pending,
            };
        }

        if let Some(next) = p.next.take() {
            let (next, future) = (p.generate)(next);
            p.inner.set(Some(future));
            p.next.set(next);
            return self.poll_next(cx);
        }

        Poll::Ready(None) // end
    }
}
```

The error reported when I do just `s.poll(cx)` in place of the todo:

```
error[E0599]: the method `poll` exists for struct `Pin<&mut Box<dyn Future<Output = T>>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:28:28
   |
28 |               return match s.poll(cx)? {
   |                              ^^^^ method cannot be called on `Pin<&mut Box<dyn Future<Output = T>>>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
  --> /rustc/5680fa18feaa87f3ff04063800aec256c3d4b4be/library/core/src/future/future.rs:37:1
   |
   = note: doesn't satisfy `_: Unpin`
  --> /rustc/5680fa18feaa87f3ff04063800aec256c3d4b4be/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:195:1
  ::: /rustc/5680fa18feaa87f3ff04063800aec256c3d4b4be/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:198:1
   |
   = note: doesn't satisfy `_: Future`
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `(dyn futures_util::Future<Output = T> + 'static): Unpin`
           which is required by `Box<(dyn futures_util::Future<Output = T> + 'static)>: futures_util::Future`
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60561573/how-can-one-await-a-result-of-a-boxed-future?

Comment: I don't *think* so `s` is already a `Pin<…>` which the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60562303/442760) reccomends I believe. But the types are really hard for me to deduce making by reasoning shaky at best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Pin<Option<...>>` doesn't make any sense; `Pin` only works if the type it wraps is a kind of pointer.

You should store `inner` as a `Option<Pin<Box<dyn Future>>>` instead and skip the structural pinning from `#[pin]`. There is no reason for the `Option<Box<...>>` itself needs to be pinned (as `#[pin]` would imply by making a `inner: Pin<&mut Option<Box<...>>>`, only the inner `dyn Future` needs to be pinned which is what a `Pin<Box<...>>` means.

In the same vein, you don't need or want `next` to be structurally pinned either. So just remove all the `#[pin]` annotations and go from there:

```
#[pin_project::pin_project]
struct BoxedStream<T, F> {
    next: Option<String>,
    inner: Option<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = T>>>>,
    generate: F,
}

impl<T, F> Stream for BoxedStream<T, F>
where
    F: Fn(String) -> (Option<String>, Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = T>>>),
{
    type Item = T;

    fn poll_next(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        let p = self.as_mut().project();
        if let Some(s) = p.inner {
            return match s.as_mut().poll(cx) {
                Poll::Ready(result) => {
                    p.inner.take();
                    Poll::Ready(Some(result))
                }
                _ => Poll::Pending,
            };
        }

        if let Some(next) = p.next.take() {
            let (next, future) = (p.generate)(next);
            *p.inner = Some(future);
            *p.next = next;
            return self.poll_next(cx);
        }

        Poll::Ready(None)
    }
}
```

I also made your function type return `Pin<Box<...>>`, it can be easily made by `Box::pin`.

Comment: Additional remark: Because OP is already using `futures_util`, he might as well use [`futures_util::future::BoxFuture`](https://docs.rs/futures-util/latest/futures_util/future/type.BoxFuture.html) to simplify his code a little.

Comment: Also, a [little example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ba29e5b23c70d6c39f19515b963fdad4) to demonstrate that the code in this answer both works and is actually usable.

Comment: Thanks, I found I aslo can solve it by take the `Box` out of `Option` and put it again if inner is pending without pin projection.